# libucrl failed to check server certificate

Tags: ssl, libcurl

I am using libcurl (in C) to login to a secure site (https). So far it was working fine. Since yesterday it is not able to login. The code looks as below.

```
bool login(char *user, char *password)
{
    bool result = false;
    CURL * curl = NULL;
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    char status_text[1024];
    CURLcode res;
    long resp_code = 0;
    int index;

    /* These fields should be collected from license file */
    char *user_field = "name";
    char *password_field = "pass";

    char *form_id_field = "form_id";
    char *form_id = "user_login";

    char *link = "https://example.com/user/login";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl == NULL) goto on_error;

    curl_easy_reset(curl);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)NULL);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res == CURLE_OK)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, link);

        /* Data should be "name=user&pass=password&form_id=user-login" */
        index = sprintf(status_text, "%s=%s&%s=%s&%s=%s",
            user_field, user, password_field,
            password, form_id_field, form_id);

        *(status_text + index) = 0x0;

        resp_code = 0;
        res = CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, status_text);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_getinfo (curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &resp_code);

        if((resp_code == 200) && (res != CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK))
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }

on_error:
    if(curl)
    {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }

    return result;
}
```

While curl_easy_perform is executed it fails. The errbuf shows error like "server certificate verification failed. cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt crlfile none". I understand it is somewhat problematic with /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file, but I did not change anything.

What may be the issue here, any hint to fix this, highly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/232445/107134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more a hint than an answer but I don't have enough rep points to comment.

> Since yesterday it is not able to login

This might be connected to the fact that Sectigo's legacy AddTrust External CA Root certificate expired on May 30, 2020 https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020

From the link above

> Certificates for your site are issued from a “chain” of issuing or “intermediate” CA that completes a path back to these trusted root certificates.

If I understand the above statement correctly, AddTrust External CA Root certificate is probably one of the certs in chain thus validation fails - at least for some clients.

EDIT

What also worked for me is this https://www.agwa.name/blog/post/fixing_the_addtrust_root_expiration

> 1. edit /etc/ca-certificates.conf and put a bang/exclamation mark (!) before mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
> 2. Run update-ca-certificates

Comment: This information helped me. I fixed it by getting new ca-bundle file from vendor and replaced it in server. I am accepting this answer.